# How to make Django unit-tests all retrieve from the same test database?

Tags: python, database, django, unit-testing

Currently when I run a set of unit-tests on Django, each test makes its own database. This means that traversing multiple features of the site all require a user sign up, login, etc.. It would be much simpler if they all fetched from the same temporary database - anyway to do this?

Comment: How about using a fixture (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/)

Comment: Is there really no simpler way? I have foreign keys upon foreign keys, and to make even one user would that quite a long time. 
If there is no other way, I guess I'll have to roll with this one.

Comment: AFAIK using foreign keys will not be a problem with fixture, you can fill your database just by using your web site as usual and than you can dump your database using ``manage.py dumpdata ..`` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata-appname-appname-appname-model) you can even generate an SQL fixture (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-sql-data) FWIW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default behavior of Django's transactional test case to perform a rollback after each test.

There is nothing preventing you, though, to have a module function, test case method or to override `TestCase.setUp()` to dynamically create test data. In fact, whenever you find yourself duplicating code, like creating the user and signing in with his credentials with the test client, you should find a way to make those bits reusable across your project's test cases.